# Using variables across different languages

Tags: python, dart

I have two code files, a python and a dart/flutter file. I am using dart/flutter to take a picture, then I want to send it to python to get the text to the image and to send the text to chatgpt to get a response.
Python:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import PIL.Image 
import cv2
import imutils
from PIL import Image 


myconfig = r"--psm 6 --oem 3"

# Replace with your image file path
img = cv2.imread("lib\math\some.jpg")

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, config=myconfig, output_type=Output.DICT) #C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe

amount_boxes = len(data['text'])

wordlist = []
word = ''

for i in range(amount_boxes):
    confidence = float(data['conf'][i])
    text = data['text'][i].strip()

    if confidence > 20 and text:
        wordlist.extend(text)
        print(f"Detected text: {text}, Confidence: {confidence}")
        (x, y, box_width, box_height) = (data['left'][i], data['top'][i], data['width'][i], data['height'][i])
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + box_width, y + box_height), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        img = cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y + box_height + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0))

for letter in wordlist:
    word += letter

print(wordlist)
print(word)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Display the image with rectangles around the detected text
```

Dart/file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class PickAnswer extends StatefulWidget {
  const PickAnswer({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PickAnswer();
  }
}

class _PickAnswer extends State<PickAnswer> {
  File? selectedImage;
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromARGB(255, 114, 17, 225),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 46, 11, 189),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _takePhoto();
          },
          child: const Text('Take a photo'),
          
        ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _takePhoto() async {
    if (counter == 0) {
      counter++;
      final returnedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (returnedImage == null) return;
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = File(returnedImage.path);
      });
      return;
    }
    if (counter != 0) {
      selectedImage = null;
      counter--;
      final returnedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (returnedImage == null) return;
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = File(returnedImage.path);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In the dart file I am asking the user to take an image, then I want to add it in the python file to turn it to text. I already have the system to get the text from an image, but I want to use the image that the user takes from the flutter/dart app. I also want to rotate the image 90 degrees. How would I do both of those things.

Comment: Are these two programs running on the same machine? In that case, could some IPC mechanism like a pipe work to transfer the data between the two?

Comment: The general answer is indeed IPC. There is no standard robust way to inspect the internal state of another process, even in the same language.

Comment: For @Mohamad: IPC is interprocess communication. When your programs are running, they aren't merely files, but rather operating system entities called processes. The same program can be run in multiple processes, for example.